# What constraints do IEEE float arithmetic provide?

Tags: floating-point, standards, ieee-754

Among the following assertions, (for a compliant implementation) which ones are guaranteed, which ones are not?

1. a+b is finite ==> a+b=b+a
2. a*b is finite ==> a*b=b*a
3. a is finite ==> a=-(-a)
4. a is finite ==> a-a=0
5. a is finite ==> 0*a=0
6. a-b=0 ==> a=b
7. a=b ==> a-b=0
8. a=b and c+a is finite ==> c+a=c+b
9. a>b ==> a-b>0
10. a-b>0 ==> a>b

(Please edit this question and make the list cover more and have an organic look.)

Comment: By '=' do you mean "bit identical" (which may matter if you want to apply these transformations in a C or C++ compiler that provides strict IEEE-754 bindings) or do you mean the "equal" predicate as defined by IEEE-754 (e.g. +0 and -0 compare as "equal", a NaN  and anything else compare not "equal") ?

Comment: Please can you edit to answer @njuffa's question? As it stands, the question is too ambiguous to be answerable. (For example, in 7, if `a` and `b` are bitwise identical floats then with the round-to-negative-infinity rounding mode, `a - b` will be negative zero. It's unclear from the question whether you'd consider that `a - b = 0` is satisfied in that situation.)

Comment: I guess the useful question here is not whether the two expressions on the RHS of each `==>` sign are *equal* in the sense of some language-supplied comparison operation, but whether they're *interchangeable* in a piece of code. And for that, you'd probably consider any two NaNs to be interchangeable with each other (few people really care about NaN signs or payloads), but you wouldn't want to consider `+0.0` and `-0.0` to be interchangeable.

Answer (score 5):

Arithmetic on the infinities does follow definite rules, so I am generalizing the question to include infinite cases. I assume you are using `=` to mean the result of comparison in IEEE floating point arithmetic, so `NaN=NaN` is false.

1. `a+b=b+a`
   True if the inputs are both finite numbers, or infinities with the same sign. False if either is a NaN, or they are infinities of opposite signs, because their sum would be a NaN.
2. `a*b=b*a`
   True unless either one of the inputs is a NaN, or they are 0 and an infinity. Again, those cases make the result a NaN.
3. `a=-(-a)` True unless `a` is a NaN.
4. `a-a=0` True unless `a` is a NaN or infinity.
5. `0*a=0` True unless `a` is a NaN or infinity.
6. `a-b=0 ==> a=b` True. `a-b` being equal to something excludes either input being a NaN or them being infinities of equal sign, the cases in which `a-b` would be a NaN. This is a case in which the interpretation of `=` matters. If the inputs are opposite sign zeros their difference is also a zero, and they compare equal under floating point arithmetic rules.
7. `a=b ==> a-b=0` True unless they are the same infinity. In that case, they compare equal but their difference is a NaN. `a=b` implies neither input is a NaN.
8. `a=b ==> c+a=c+b` False if `c` is a NaN, or the inputs are all infinite and `c` has the opposite sign from `a` and `b`. True in all other cases. `a=b` implies neither of them is a NaN.
9. `a>b ==> a-b>0` True. `a>b` implies neither input is a NaN.
10. `a-b>0 ==> a>b` True. `a-b>0` implies neither input is a NaN.